# Question about the Definition of the "Gather"

Tags: basketball

so, in the NBA rulebook, it says: "The gather is defined as the point where the player gains enough control of the ball to hold it, change hands, pass, shoot, or the player cradles the ball against his body."

I understand everything but the meaning of "changing hands."
what does it mean?

Much appreciated.